# if Child Categories, esle show Entries

Tags: child-categories

I'm looking to show parent categories that have children, but if parents have no children, I need to show channel entries for the parent cats using the same segment_3.

```
{if "child_categories"!=""}
   This Has Child Categories
     {if:else}
   This Doesn't - Show Entries in Parent 
{/if}
```

Edit:  Trying this:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories cat_url_title="{segment_2}" max_depth="2"} 
{if '{has_children_in_output}' != ''} 
This Has Stuff Show Children Cats 
{if:else} This Doesn't Have Children - Show Entries for Parent Cat 
{/if} {/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

I'm just not sure whow to show entries inside GW Cat tags.  Maybe I need to store GW output as a variable to reuse in a Channel Tag?

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that GWCode Categories has not been updated since 2012, and only works with EE2 (see more details here http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/release-notes) - so while it is incredibly handy it is not a robust long-term solution.

Fortunately there is an alternatives - find out more here https://buzzingpixel.com/software/category-construct/documentation/template-tags

As for doing the conditional you are trying to do, you probably can do it using the `{construct:has_children}` tag - which would seem to do all you need.

HTH

Comment: There's a beta for EE3 but it's kind of a use at your own risk kinda thing.  https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/gwcode-categories/viewthread/15375

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a solution.

```
{exp:gwcode_categories cat_url_title="{segment_2}" max_depth="1" style="linear"}
{if '{has_children_in_output}' != ''}
{!-- Show Nothing --}
{if:else}
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" custom_fields="yes" category="{segment_category_ids}"}
          <!-- Your Stuff -->
{/exp:channel:entries}      
{/if} 
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```